# ¿Cómo permitir peticiones GET a la API REST desde otros sitios?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, rest

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en javascript, para leer los posts desde un sitio de WordPress, y cargarlos en una galería.

Solamente es para consultar los posts, no para enviar artículos ni editar nada desde la API. Por lo que solo requiero autorizar el método GET.

La documentación para la versión 1 del plugin no funciona, ya que han cambiado los hooks y las funciones.

¿Cómo habilitar por lo menos el acceso GET, a fin de que nos permita trabajar con la API para consultar contenidos?

Comment: En que archivo del Wordpress se agrega?

Comment: En un plugin activo para que sea portable aunque cambies de temas, o en el functions.php de tu tema, serían los lugares recomendables para empezar. De los archivos de WordPress en realidad no deberías tocar nada.

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta incluyendo un ejemplo de plugin "completo" que contenga la función, de modo que pueda fácilmente portarse entre instancias de WP independientemente del tema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de investigar la [función](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rest_send_cors_headers/) y [el hook correspondiente](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_pre_serve_request/) que envía las cabeceras de [Access-Control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), pude localizar por fin una referencia que sí funciona para permitirme desarrollar una aplicación web con JavaScript en un sitio distinto que la instalación de WordPress.

Y [basándome en este ejemplo](http://joshpress.net/access-control-headers-for-the-wordpress-rest-api/), comparto la solución en formato de archivo de plugin "completo" (listo para activarse desde la interfaz de WordPress):

```
<?php
/**
 * @wordpress-plugin
 * Plugin Name:       Allow GET access to world
 * Plugin URI:        http://bit.ly/2b1Z5sV
 * Description:       Allow GET access to world
 * Version:           0.0.1
 * Author:            Jesús Franco
 * Author URI:        http://tzkmx.wordpress.com
 * License:           GPL-2.0+
 * License URI:       http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.txt
 */

// If this file is called directly, abort.
if ( ! defined( 'WPINC' ) ) {
    die;
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function() {

     /* desenganchamos la función predeterminada */
     remove_filter('rest_pre_serve_request', 'rest_send_cors_headers');

     /* y añadimos nuestro propio filtro */
     add_filter('rest_pre_serve_request', function( $value ) {
          $origin = get_http_origin();
          if ( $origin ) {
              header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . esc_url_raw( $origin ) );
          } else {
              header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . esc_url_raw( site_url() ) );
          }
          header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET' );

          return $value;
     });
}, 15);
```

Puedes vaciar el contenido de este snippet a una ruta como `wp-content/plugins/get-rest-world-access/get-rest-world-access.php`

En el código original asigna dos veces el encabezado, con lo que otros sitios vuelven a quedar fuera.

Espero sirva para quiénes han lidiado como su servidor, con este problema.